# How to make regex that wouldn't allow anything except numbers separated by a comma?

Tags: php, regex, string

I have a `regex`, which is: `/[0-9]+(,[0-9]+)*/`.

It accepts only numbers, separated by a comma. For instance:

```
1,2,3,4 = good
,1,2,3,4 = bad
1,2,3,4, = bad
String = bad
```

But it also accepts a numbers with a space:

```
1, 2, 3, 4 = good
```

How to make regex that wouldn't allow to do so and would only let to enter a numbers, separated by a comma without spaces?

Comment: You may try this `[\d](,[\d\S])*` where `\S` means not white space. I've removed the `+` because would validate for `123,2,34,345` too

Comment: @enxaneta That would allow any non whitespace character. `µ`, `!`, `a`, etc.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your regex is correct as is, you just need to use [anchors](https://www.regular-expressions.info/anchors.html) so you check the full string, and not a partial match.

```
^[0-9]+(,[0-9]+)*$
```

https://regex101.com/r/zU22VX/1/

An alternative approach could be:

```
$string = '1,2,3,4';
$array = str_getcsv($string);
foreach($array as $number) {
    if(!is_numeric($number)) {
        echo 'Bad value' . $number;
        break;
    }
}
```

Comment: Someone must be bored today, just downvoting old questions?

Answer (score 1):

This should work:

```
/^\d(,\d)*$/
```

- `^` match the beginning of the string
- `\d` match a digit
- `$` match
  the end of the string

Example:

```
if (preg_match("/^\d(,\d)*$/", $string))
    echo "good";
else
    echo "bad";
```

Comment: Both `\d`s should have quantifiers.

Answer (score 0):

Use this:

```
^(\d,(?=\d))*\d$
```

How it works:

- `^`: match strings which starts with..(what follows)
- `(...)*`: what inside the brackets can be repeated any number of times
- `\d,(?=\d)`: this is the block that is allowed to repeat. It looks for a number from 0 to 9 followed by a comma which is followed by a number. The number following the comma is not included in the match.
- `\d$`: finally, the string must terminate with a number.

Comment: `(?=\d)` is redundant, if you remove it, it will work the same. The best (=the most efficient) way to write the regex is `^\d(?:,\d)*$`

Comment: Good solution! I didn't know the group construct `(?:)`